# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint but I already use Convert.ToInt64

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqlparameter

I have a input textbox in my view what only accept number:

```
<input asp-for="order" class="form-control" MaxLength="120" type="number" />
```

`Order` is a `bigint` column in the database table.

Then in the controller I write the following code:

```
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@order", Convert.ToInt64(obj.order)));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@extra", obj.extra));

var objList = _db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("update @order, @extra", parameters.ToArray());
```

But I keep getting the same error whatever I try to change. The error is:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Also when I just put a number in the `SqlParameter` it's not working like:

```
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@order", Convert.ToInt64("10000")));
```

The update stored procedure is just very simple:

```
(
    @extra nvarchar(MAX),
    @order bigint
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.table
    SET extra = @extra 
    WHERE order = @order
END
RETURN 0
```

Comment: What type is the field **extra** in table **table**? is it `bigint` or `nvarchar`?

Comment: extra is an nvarchar(max)

I solved it now after many many hours by changing the code from an array to individual parameters. 

var order = new SqlParameter("@order", order);
var objList = _db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("update @order, @extra", order, extra);

I still don't understand why the array was the problem ?

Comment: No i'm not do. I don't see in the coding there is a list of orders

Comment: the `parameters` parameter is declared as `params object[]`. Your array of parameters is probably not recognized as such array but instead used as first item in a compiler generated `object[]` array, and then converted to its string representation as something like **"SqlParameter[]"**.